Provide data from Jest test cases to reporters
I have a question regarding Jest, Junit and XRay.
I'm looking for a way to provide testcase metadata to jest-junit reporter or any custom reporter. The end goal is to be able to provide testcase properties (example: test_key, requirements, test_summary, etc) to XRay by defining them in the test code.
One example of what it could look like:
describe('positive numbers', () => {
    it('should add up', 
       { xray: { testKey: 'TEST-123', requirements: ['REQ-1', 'REQ-2'] } }, // What I'd like to be able to add 
       () => { expect(1 + 2).toBe(3); }
    );
});

This data would be forwarded in testResults so that reporters could access it and transform it. Using jest-junit, we could achieve this by defining a junitTestCaseProperties.js script pretty easily.
All I want is being able to generate following JUnit report:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites name="jest tests" tests="1" failures="0" errors="0" time="0.661">
  <testsuite name="positive numbers" errors="0" failures="0" skipped="0" timestamp="2024-04-09T14:15:50" time="0.633" tests="1">
    <testcase classname="test.spec.ts" name="positive numbers - should add up" time="0.002">
      <properties>
        <property name="test_key" value="TEST-123"/>
        <property name="requirement" value="REQ-1"/>
        <property name="requirement" value="REQ-2"/>
      </properties>
    </testcase>
  </testsuite>
</testsuites>


Any idea, if that's possible? It doesn't have to be exactly achieved as suggested.
If you have alternate solutions achieving the same result by defining metadata at testcase level I'm open to it 
Thank you in advance for your help !
I searched on stackoverflow, GitHub and google to find solution to this. I didn't found anything.
I'm able to generate testcase properties using jest-junit but not related with test metadata.

Currently this seems to be not supported by jest-junit; there's a feature request for having this, so I would suggest leaving there your feedback so the jest-junit maintainers can have a look at it.
At this point, jest-junit seems to have some sort of support for having test case level properties based on a configuration file; however, that doesn't provide you the ability to inject it at runtime as an argument at each test case level, as jest doesn't support it; the syntax for the test or it block, is something like test(name, fn, timeout).
